# Appium iOS Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file

Tags: ios, iphone, selenium, appium, appium-ios

When I am running appium on real iPhone, appium gives below error. I did not found any solution for that.

```
[XCUITest] Using WDA path: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent'
[XCUITest] Using WDA agent: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj'

[XCUITest] Beginning test with command 'xcodebuild build-for-testing test-without-building -project /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -configuration Debug IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.0' in directory '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent'

[Xcode] 2017-11-04 17:13:55.690 xcodebuild[3522:289240] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/tcs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdc48f69390 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}


[XCUITest] Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65
    at XCUITestDriver.quitAndUninstall$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:374:15)
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65
    at XCUITestDriver.quitAndUninstall$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:374:15)
```

I found that xcode not able to make the build.

```
[XCUITest] Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65
    at XCUITestDriver.quitAndUninstall$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:374:15)
```

Answer (score 1):

WebDriverAgent - Configure properly as per the instruction then try it out. https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

WebdriverAgent is not opened in your real device before starting execution on the device. I faced similar issue and resolved by following the below steps.

1. Sign the WebDriverAgent project in Xcode
2. Build the project and then click Product-> Test. This will launch the WebdriverAgent in your real device.
3. Start the appium.